# flex- facing issue on moving to bin release

Tags: apache-flex, deployment, flex4

We are hosting a flex product on Azure. Till recently we were using the bin debug version and things were working, albeit slow. When we switched to the bin-release version, we are facing 2 errors

a) In some cases, the switching between modules doesn't work.(We have a parent container that calls the modules). On pressing Back button, parent container flips out module B, but not able to get in module A

b) Module A/B are unable to call an xml file, resident on the server using url-loader.

As we don't get any error reported for these, I am not clear where the issue is.

Do these issues pertain to security/ mistakes in deployment? Any pointers will help

Thanks

Comment: How are you switching between modules?  What are the cases where it doesn't work?  When you say "Module" Are you referring to an actual Module ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/modules/Module.html ) or are you using the term generically? How do Module A/B call an XML File?  Have you tried a network sniffer to try to spot potential issues w/ the request?

Comment: I am referring to Module mx:Module; I can't see any reason why the switch behaves inconsistently. On the xml files being called, I just checked the bin release folder vs bin debug folder: these XML's are MISSING!! Is that the reason for the XML issue- any compiler setting for the bin release version to be done?

Comment: If XML Files are missing; then yes that would definitely cause issues in them being called.  And depending on your code it could back-pedal to introduce other errors.  When compiling for Flash Builder, there is an option to copy non-embedded assets to the debug folder; but it doesn't appear to be a compiler option, so it must be something that FB does automatically, and you'll have to do manually for the release build.